# how to deal with custom events in ember.js component?

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I've got some problems to understand its philosophy. I know *actions up, data down* but in real life, lets say I have [Fotorama](http://fotorama.io/) initialized in my-gallery component (I don't know if that is ok, but I did it in       `didInsertElement` method). This library has its own events. They could look like this in plain JS:

```
$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:ready', function (e, fotorama) {});
```

or:

```
$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:show', function () {});
```

but I feel in Ember, those should be somehow mapped into actions in component.
My question is: how? I need to fire some actions (to be catched by another components or maybe a router) inside those actions. So I think it should be like this: `this.sendAction('actionName', actionParams);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep component reference to call sendAction method.

```
didInsertElement(){
 this._super(...arguments);
 var _this=this;
 this.$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:show', function () {
  _this.sendAction('actionName', actionParams);
 });
}
willDestroyElement(){
 this._super(...arguments);
 this.$('.fotorama').off('fotorama:show')
}
```

If we find an better answer to this question. I will happily remove my answer.

Comment: Can you provide docs or more info, why this approach is not recommended?

Comment: _didInsertElement() is also a good place to attach event listeners. This is particularly useful for custom events or other browser events which do not have a built-in event handler._ from [ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code)

Comment: I usually write code like this when I deal with jquery plugins. but there is conception around ember folks that most of the jquery plugins will not play nicely with ember.  so we need to write it our own...I simply added `not recommended approach` to avoid getting more down votes ha ha :).  @locks may enlighten us.

Comment: _most of the jquery plugins will not play nicely with ember. so we need to write it our own_. Absolutely! But when I begin to write our own implementation, I feel something is wrong that I'm re-inventing the wheels.

Comment: your answer together with adding actionName='actionName' to {{my-gallery}} works for me (I missed that part)

Comment: @kumkanillam I do not know a better alternative to what you have suggested. I would also be happy to learn if there is a better way.

Comment: This is the recommended approach as far as I know. Edited to clarify that

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem. I need to have a third party library talk to my ember app so I registered a custom event in my ember app:

```
const App = Ember.Application.extend({
  customEvents: {
    foo: 'foo',
  },
});
```

Then triggered it from third party code:

```
<a href="..." onclick="$(this).trigger('foo'); return false;">
```

And, in a component, write the handler for that event according to the docs:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  foo(event) {
    console.warn('event happened', event);
  },
});
```

See:
* https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/components/handling-events/
* https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Application/properties/customEvents?anchor=customEvents

Comment: Why do you end your answer with `Is this answer helpful?`. If it was helpful, then they would simply upvote the post, that's what it's there for. I think it's noise.

Comment: I have never asked before. Just wanted to see what happened.