# Catch an iframe load event in Ember

Tags: javascript, iframe, ember.js

I need to know when an iframe has loaded its content, and I'm trying to stick to the Ember way of doing things.

```
<iframe src="" {{action "onLoad" on="load"}}></iframe>
```

It seems pretty simple and straightforward, but that action is never getting called. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Or perhaps a better way of detecting this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

Create component named my-component, In my-component.hbs

```
<iframe src="" onload={{action "onLoading"}}></iframe>
```

in my-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({    
    actions: {
        onLoading() {
            console.log('OnLoad');
        }
    }
});
```

This will work even if its not in component too.

---

Here you can find the list of events supported.https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/handling-events/#toc_event-names

But there is no mentioning for the `load`. so I suspect you need to mention this with custom events.
You can try define `onload` event in customEvents object in `app.js` file

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
    modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
    podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
    Resolver,
    customEvents:{
      load:'load'
    }
});
```

Refer:
https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14.0/classes/Ember.Application/properties/customEvents?anchor=customEvents

Comment: PS: I haven't done this, I will be surprised if its works

Comment: @ZacharyNicoll I updated my answer. using DOM event straight away instead of using Ember event

Comment: I like it! Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great, but this does the trick in lieu of any better solutions.

```
import Ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  activate() {
    Ember.run.schedule('render', () => {
      Ember.$('iframe').one('load', () => { this.send('onLoad') })
    })
  }
})
```

This runs after the route's template has finished rendering, every time the route is entered. It catches the load event from the iframe and manually fires off the action to let Ember take things over. Not perfect, but not awful either.

Comment: Hey refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229752/how-to-deal-with-custom-events-in-ember-js-component/41233244#41233244) Actually you need to `off` event in `deactivate` hook. preferred way is create component do this in `didInsertElement` and remove it in `willDestroyElement` hook

Comment: Good point @kumkanillam, the further I go with it, the more it seems like it belongs in a component.